# Pack data, extreme Bitpacking in Python

Tags: python, numpy, compression, bitstring

I need to pack information as closely as possible into a bitstream.

I have variables with a different number of distinct states:

```
Number_of_states=[3,5,129,15,6,2]# A bit longer in reality
```

The best option I have in the Moment would be to create a bitfield, using

2+3+8+4+3+1 bit ->21 bit

However it should be possible to pack these states into `np.log2(3*5*129*15*6*2)=18.4` bits, saving two bits. (In reality I have 298 bits an need to save a few)

In my case this would save about >5% of the data stream, which would help a lot.

Is there a viable solution in python to pack the data in this way? I tried `packalgorithms`, but they create too much overhead with just a few bytes of data. The string is no problem, it is constant and will be transmitted beforehand.

This is the code I am using in the moment:

```
from bitstring import pack
import numpy as np

DATA_TO_BE_PACKED=np.zeros(6)

Number_of_states=[3,5,129,15,6,2]#mutch longer in reality

DATA_TO_BE_PACKED=np.random.randint(Number_of_states)

string=''

for item in Number_of_states:
    string+='uint:{}, '.format(int(np.ceil(np.log2(item))))

PACKED_DATA = pack(string,*DATA_TO_BE_PACKED)

print(len(PACKED_DATA ))

print(PACKED_DATA.unpack(string))
```

Comment: Output? Why numpy?

Comment: I would thought numpy might be a solution to perform the nessesary calculations, bitstring is not it. The output is the packed string s.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean with states. It looks like all you mean is data..?  Tried `zlib.compress(..)`?

Comment: I tried zlib.compress, and it created to mutch overhead, the stream is currently only 43 bytes, any overhead does not help. I need to get it to <40bytes.
By states I mean variables that accept x distict states. So not 256 like an int8, only for exampe 6 (needing an int2.something, currently I am using an int3, which takes to mutch space

Comment: well... decimal 6 is binary 110, so how you're going to store that in two bytes escapes me..?  I'm assuming the receiver knows at least the size of the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a usecase of a [mixed radix numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix).

A quick proof of concept:

```
num_states = [3, 5, 129, 15, 6, 2]
input_data = [2, 3, 78, 9, 0, 1]
print("Input data: %s" % input_data)
```

To encode, you start with a 0, and for each state first multiply by number of states, and then add the current state:

```
encoded = 0
for i in range(len(num_states)):
    encoded *= num_states[i]
    encoded += input_data[i]

print("Encoded: %d" % encoded)
```

To decode, you go in reverse, and get remainder of division by number of states, and then divide by number of states:

```
decoded_data = []
for n in reversed(num_states):
    v = encoded % n
    encoded = encoded // n
    decoded_data.insert(0, v)

print("Decoded data: %s" % decoded_data)
```

Example output:

```
Input data: [2, 3, 78, 9, 0, 1]
Encoded: 316009
Decoded data: [2, 3, 78, 9, 0, 1]
```

Another example with more values:

```
Input data: [2, 3, 78, 9, 0, 1, 84, 17, 4, 5, 30, 1]
Encoded: 14092575747751
Decoded data: [2L, 3L, 78L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 84L, 17L, 4L, 5L, 30L, 1L]
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, and I am impressed by python 3 handling of very large integers. The decoding hardware will be C (I did not mention that in the question) so I am not sure how they will handle the decoding. Might be nessesary to limit the length to 64 bit each.

Answer (score 3):

You can interpret the state as an index into a multidimensional array with shape (3, 5, 129, 15, 6, 2).  This index can be encoded as the integer index into the flattened 1-d array with length `3*5*129*15*6*2 = 348300`. NumPy has the functions `ravel_multi_index` and `unravel_index` that can do this for you.

For example, let `num_states` be the number of states for each component of your state:

```
In [86]: num_states = [3, 5, 129, 15, 6, 2]
```

Suppose `state` holds an instance of the data; that is, it records the state of each component:

```
In [87]: state = [2, 3, 78, 9, 0, 1]
```

To encode this state, pass it through `ravel_multi_index`.  `idx` is the encoded state:

```
In [88]: idx = np.ravel_multi_index(state, num_states)

In [89]: idx
Out[89]: 316009
```

By construction, `0 <= idx < 348300`, so it requires only 19 bits.

To restore `state` from `idx`, use `unravel_index`:

```
In [90]: np.unravel_index(idx, num_states)
Out[90]: (2, 3, 78, 9, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Nice approach, but given that OP's number of states is "a bit longer in reality", I'm afraid the lookup array will quickly explode to intractable size.

Comment: @DanMašek, good point--the NumPy functions won't handle `len(num_states)` > 32, and won't handle the huge integers involved.  I was about to add a pure Python equivalent of `ravel_multi_index` and `unravel_index`, but you've already done it :).

Comment: Oh, DOH on my part, for not realizing ravel/unravel just does an index calculation, even though you explicitly mention it. My brain is still warming up :D